# Delete all records in All Subscribers List at once

Tags: marketing-cloud, list, contact, subscriber

We're doing some data cleanup here and need to delete all records from the All Subscribers List.  I've seen several suggestions regarding exporting all the records from All Subscribers to a CSV, then creating a new List using this CSV, then deleting the List and selecting the option to delete them from the All Subscribers List.

The problem is that we have about 7M+ records in our All Subscribers List, and I cannot get this List to export successfully.  It ran for 4 hours and only got to 3% before I killed that process.  Any other suggestions for purging all these records?

Comment: You can write an SSJS and put it a part of automation .. and leave it running ..

Comment: SSJS script activities have a 30 minute timeout window just like queries.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the SOAP and REST APIs and didn't see much.  Looping through that many records seems infeasible.  And I didn't see any bulk method for just deleting all records from All Subscribers.  

Looking into dataloader.io as I do not see Data Loader or Contact Builder activated for our Marketing Cloud account.  Not seeing too many options.

Answer (score 1):

[**Contact Delete**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5) in the parent business unit allows you to do this

You're limited to doing 1M subscribers at a time, so you'll have to find some way to break up your 7M into groups.  I'd recommend querying the [**_Subscribers**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5) data view and writing the groups to separate sendable data extensions.

It's not a fast process.  I've yet to have a large contact delete process complete without the involvement of SF Support.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but thanks!  This is the avenue I'm researching now.  Apparently Contact Builder isn't enabled for our account or something because I don't see anything under Audience Builder.  I'm following up with their support regarding this, but it seems to be straight forward.  

Any gotchas I should be aware of?

Thanks!